# horizontal scroll bar issues

Tags: java, android, button, scroll

not sure what issues i have with horizontal scroll bar with buttons inside please pardon me but i am brand new to java and android coding error is `This HorizontalScrollView layout or its LinearLayout parent is possibly useless`

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tabHost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Html"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="60dp" >

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/lesson1" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/lesson2" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/lesson3" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </HorizontalScrollView>

                </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/CSS"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="60dp" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Javascript"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="60dp" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Comment: It just means you do not need a `LinearLayout` since the `HorizontalScrollView` is the only child of the `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 0):

The warning means that you can remove either the HorizontalScrollView or its "@+id/Html" LinearLayout parent view with no signicant loss to your layout. It occurs because HorizontalScrollView is the only child of the "@+id/Html" LinearLayout.

I used to nest LinearLayouts like this until I learned to use RelativeLayout. I recommend that you get used to it too, it is much easier to handle layouts that way: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html